# EDITED: How can I output value from Custom Object record in a VF page on Force.com site, using existing controller?

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object

We have a custom object: Custom_Switches__c. Within that object, we have a record: Turn_On__c (checkbox). We need to output the value from Turn_On__c in a VF page. If it helps, the ID of Turn_On__c is a08180000005lj9.

The VF page already uses a controller called pkb_Controller. We want to add any necessary Apex code to the to the current controller pkb_Controller, since pkb_Controller is used on the VF page already.

Overview:

- object name: Custom_Switches__c
- record name: Turn_On__c
- record ID (if needed): a08180000005lj9

Goal: Output value from Turn_On__c on a VF page, using pkb_Controller to house any apex code.

[image]

[image]

Here is the structure of the custom controller, so far as I can tell. I tried putting custom controller code here from the docs page, but I couldn't make it work. Any tips on how to place apex code in this structure to call the custom field/record would be great!

public without sharing class pkb_Controller
{
    public pkb_Controller()
    {

```
}

/* ***** CONTROLLER EXTENSION CONSTRUCTOR ***** */
public pkb_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController sc)
{

}
```

}

Here's what I have so far:

Controller:

```
public pkb_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController sc)
{   
    sc.addFields(new List<String> {'Custom_Switches__c.Turn_On__c'});
}
```

VF page:

I've tried the following:

The pkbCon. is used a lot to access  Here's where it's constructed I think:

```
/* ***** HANDLE TO CURRENT INSTANCE OF CONTROLLER (to be passed to rendered VF components, avoids re-instantiation of controller) ***** */
public pkb_Controller pkbCon { get { return this; } }
```

***Getting a specific record***

I did not realize it before, but turns out we need to get a specific record, not just the custom field value. The record is called "Phone". The Phone record, and each record like it, has the Turn_On__c field in it as a boolean value. We need that value from the specified record. This case, phone.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What if there is 2 or more Turn On records created? Which one do you want to output?

Comment: I think Turn On is a field, not a record

Comment: If there are 2 or more fields, like Turn_On__c and Turn_On_2__c, I'd like to output the individual field value in the VF page one at a time, just like @CaspNZ noted: {!customSwitch.Turn_On__c} and {!customSwitch.Turn_On_2__c}.

However, the tricky part for me is putting the code into the custom controller which will allow me to use this tag in a VF page: {!customSwitch.Turn_On__c}. I just don't know where to put it, or what the code should be.

Comment: @Bachovski - Good question. I'd like to be able to output each one, such as:  {!customSwitch.Turn_On__c.Phone}. That would specific the "Phone" record. Or maybe it should be {!customSwitch.Phone.Turn_On__c}

Answer (score 2):

### Updated with extra instructions

If you are extending a `StandardController` you would add the field using this method:

```
yourstandardcontroller.addFields(new List<String> {'Custom_Switches__c.Turn_On__c'});
```

Add this in the constructor of your controller. Just copy and paste it in and change the name from `yourstandardcontroller` to the name of the controller passed into the constructor.

Your controller constructor code will look like:

```
public pkb_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController sc){
    sc.addFields(new List<String> {'Custom_Switches__c.Turn_On__c'});
}
```

If you have a completely custom Controller, you will need to find where you are getting your `Custom_Switches__c` record and add `Turn_On__c` to the query.
There will be a statement that starts like:

```
List<Custom_Switches__c> switches = [SELECT Field_1, Field_2...];
```

Put a comma after one of the field names and put your field there. Then it will become available for use after this query is executed.

Once you have the record, it'll be saved to the controller and will have a publicly exposed sObject variable (I'm assuming not a list).

In your VF page, you'll refer to this sObject variable (probably called `customSwitch` or something similar) using the standard Visualforce binding syntax - `{![your expression]}`

The simplest example would be to write something like

```
<apex:outputText value="{!customSwitch.Turn_On__c}"/>
```

**Edit** I see you have tried a couple of things to get the field on the page.
You should use the same format that the other fields are using - there must be some others on the page for you to use as an example.

**Edit 2** You can add this specific field to your custom controller as a property if you like, by amending your constructor to this:

```
public Custom_Switches__c switches {get;set;}

public pkb_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController sc){

    sc.addFields(new List<String> {'Custom_Switches__c.Turn_On__c'});
    this.switches = (Custom_Switches__c)sc.getRecord();
}
```

Then you can use:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!switches.Turn_On__c}"/>
```

Comment: Yes, it is a complete custom controller. It's a very large file, but I'll add some of the code from the controller to my question above. :)

Comment: Thanks for the sample code! I'm not quite there. :( I'll update the question with what I have.

Comment: Amended my answer - see text at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, @CaspNZ! It's a great answer. I checked with our CRM Admin and I was told there are, in fact, specific records under this custom object (i added screenshots above). So we need to get each specific record, such as: {!customSwitch.Turn_On__c.PhoneRecord}, {!customSwitch.Turn_On__c.ChatRecord}, etc.

Comment: This changes quite a bit. What exactly does the VisualForce page need to display? What is the context of the data? (ie are you on a parent record of some type, looking at child records? Are you wanting a list of child records?

Comment: Each record is a toggle--a switch--On/off. The value of that record (true/false) will be output on our force.com site. Then we'll use VF/Javascript to toggle the visibility of certain elements based on that value.

Comment: One more question - what does the page the your pkb_Controller controls look like? Is it a list of records? It sounds like a list controller...

Comment: The page is a VF page that is customer-facing. A website page.  <apex:page cache="false"
  standardStylesheets="false"
  showHeader="false"
  sidebar="false"
  standardController="KnowledgeArticle"
  extensions="pkb_Controller"
  language="{!selectedLanguage}"
  applyBodyTag="false"
  applyHtmlTag="false"
  ></apex:page>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23272/discussion-between-caspnz-and-alan).

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding another answer here, as I think it will be clearer. I'm not going to remove my original answer, as I feel it was correct for the information I had at the time.

What you want is a list of `Custom_Switch__c` records, obtained by the existing KnowledgeArticle controller extension.

Inside your constructor, perform a query for all `Custom_Switch__c` records.

Then render this list to the VF page, indicating if turned on or not.

Controller Snippet:

```
public Custom_Switches__c switches {get;set;}
public Boolean phone {get;set;}
public Boolean chat {get;set;}

public pkb_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController sc){
    List<Custom_Switches__c> switches = [SELECT Turn_On__c, Name 
                                         FROM Custom_Switches__c ];
    for (Custom_Switches__c switch : switches){
        if (switch.Name == 'Phone'){
            phone = true;
        }
        else if (switch.Name == 'Chat'){
            chat = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:outputtext rendered="{!phone == true}" value="Phone" />
<apex:outputtext rendered="{!chat == true}" value="Chat"/>
```

If you need to add more items, add to both the query and the `outputputtext` elements in the vf page.